# background blue button image obj c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, background

I'm assigning to a button two different types of image..

something happens to me that I can't understand .. it creates a sort of background for the blue image

```
        [self.shippingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage customImageWithName:@"terms_and_conditions_unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.shippingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage customImageWithName:@"terms_and_conditions_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self.billingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage customImageWithName:@"terms_and_conditions_unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.billingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage customImageWithName:@"terms_and_conditions_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


- (IBAction)shippingButtonChanged:(id)sender {
    self.shippingButton.selected = !self.shippingButton.selected;
}

- (IBAction)billingButtonChanged {
    self.billingButton.selected = !self.billingButton.selected;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMLYy.png)

[upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8BkO.png)

Comment: Why you set image to background?. Directly set it to button fore view. Like [self.shippingButton setImage:@"image.png"  forState:];

Comment: @phani i have upload image, i try with setImage and now is that..

Comment: Check button back ground colour. Not sure, but try to set btn.backGroundColor to white.

Comment: @phani not work bro..

Comment: Did you use story board for button? or programatically?
If Programatically, then share the code. 
StoryBoard, check the tint and bg colors.